# facebook api, getting comment likes, not just like_count

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Using the facebook graph api explorer, I am trying to get the 'likes' for a comment in a public group. The request I am using is

```
->/v2.1/340032752841177?fields=feed{message,comments{likes,message,from,like_count}}
```

Where 340032752841177 is the group id. The tool accepts this request ok, but it quietly doesn't return the 'likes' list on the comments:

```
    "comments": {
      "data": [
        {
          "message": "Henry's comment.", 
          "from": {
            "id": "830700716960157", 
            "name": "Henry Carmichael"
          }, 
          "like_count": 1, 
          "id": "340035706174215"
        }
      ],
```

I would have expected the likes list to appear in the dictionary above.

In another SO question I learned I can get the likes of a single comment like this:

```
->/v2.1/340032752841177_340035436174242_340035706174215/likes

"data": [
{
  "id": "10152551090402608", 
  "name": "Charlie Burns"
}
],
```

Where 340032752841177_340035436174242 is the post id and 340035706174215 is the comment id.

The problem with this approach is that I have to do a request for each comment and I am parsing a large facebook group with many comments.

Is there a way to get the 'likes' of comments without having to do each comment individually? Thanks.

Comment: I wound up using the batch facility that let me do 50 api requests for each http request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cant get the list of likes for comments with one call, only the number of them.

If you try running `->/v2.1/340032752841177/feed?fields=comments.summary(true)` you can get
all the fields that can be returned for the comments endpoint. A sample response is:

```
"comments": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "340035706174215", 
            "from": {
              "id": "830700716960157", 
              "name": "Henry Carmichael"
            }, 
            "message": "Henry's comment.", 
            "can_remove": false, 
            "created_time": "2014-10-06T15:21:55+0000", 
            "like_count": 1, 
            "user_likes": false
          }
        ]
```

As you see there is no full list of likes and comments endpoint isn't returning any more inforamtion.
That is all.

Futhermore you can check it from the Graph API Explorer. Here is a screenshot of the available fields
in the comments endpoint:

[image]

As you see there is not a "likes_list" field, so again there is no way that you can get the list of likes for the comments.

The only solution is the one you are suggesting. One request for each comment

Comment: If you look at the screenshot above, under the "connections" section there is "likes". So, if I ask for the "likes" connection, I get a list of likes.